# try to show html tags as text with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a string that contains HTML tags.
I want to render as an HTML element only the span tags aka `<span></span>`.
every other tag that is not a span tag should be treated as regular text.

The result I'm trying to achieve is to color any text that I want even if it contains HTML tags.

I fail.

is there any other technique that I can try or a workaround?

```
var problem = ["<h1>","</h1>"];

var red_text = "<span style='color:red'>i am red </span>";

var green_text = "<span style='color:green'>" +
                                problem[0] + 
                                "i am green" +
                                problem[1] +
                                "</span>";

//the real result should have <h1> </h1>
var expected_text = red_text + "<span style='color:green'>|h1|i am green|/h1|</span>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = red_text + green_text;

document.getElementById("expected").innerHTML = expected_text;
```

HTML and JavaScript code at :
https://jsfiddle.net/ytLftxww/1/

Comment: You should escape your string. Search for "escape html string javascript" that you will find tons of answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use HTML entities to escape the `<` and `>` in those tags.

For example: `"<span style='color:green'>&lt;h1&gt;i am green&lt;/h1&gt;</span>"`

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ytLftxww/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
var problem = ["&lt;h1&gt;","&lt;h1&gt;"];
```

does unescaping the < > work for you?

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytLftxww/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&lt` for `<` and & `&gt` for `>`.